# What is a non-topological manifold (if such a thing exists)?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, manifolds

So in my wikipedia readings, I have often stumbled across mentions of topological manifolds. I thought a manifold intrinsically had to be topological, either explicitly or implicitly like in a metric space. I don't even know how to conceptualise a non-topological manifold. Is this just wikipedia being weird, or are non-toplogical manifolds a thing, and if they are, what are they? Are there any examples I can see? And do they generalise topological manifolds, or are they their own thing?

Comment: I see no reason why manifolds couldn't be based on [Cech closure spaces](https://www.google.com/search?q="cech+closure+space") or other [generalized topological structures](https://www.google.com/search?q=generalized+topology), although I doubt much of interest would arise from such things (by the way, saying this guarantees the opposite). However, the answer by @Arnaud Mortier is the real reason.

Answer (score 6):

You use ***topological*** to emphasize the fact that your manifold doesn't have additional structure or properties, such as a *[differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold)* structure, or a *[piecewise linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_manifold)* structure, where the transition maps have extra requirements on top of being ***continuous***.

If you were to write "let $X$ be a manifold", the reader would possibly wonder what class of manifolds you are considering.